# Removing the element in a list occuring more than once

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, data-structures

I have a list and don't know all the values but I want to remove all the values which occurs more than once and only one of that value is left.Suppose here is the list:

```
lst = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four','four','five','five','five']
```

This is what I need:

```
lst = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four','five']
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
i=0
for ele in lst:
if ele[i] in lst:
    lst.remove(ele[i])
```

but it's not working.

Comment: Try `list(set(lst))` but it won't preserve the order

Answer (score 2):

This works pretty well:

```
lst = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four','four','five','five','five']
newList = list(dict.fromkeys(lst))
print(newList)
```

output: `['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five']`

Comment: The complicated version of using a `set`.

Comment: Is there any method to use a loop and something like list.pop() or list.remove()?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? It only requires more computing to do that.

Comment: @Uber I am basically trying to solve the problems logically without using functions.I have made an algorithm for it but cannot convert it to code.